# Cannot link image from server

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, react-native, cpanel

```
<Image source={{uri: 'https://myserver.com/myproject/images/dog.jpg'}} style={{ height: 200, width: null, flex: 1 }} />
```

I need to link an image from my server. I could open the link through the web browser, but I could not see the image in the app. The server is on cPanel, and I set all permissions to 0777 (although it's not safe to do so). The hotlink protection is disabled, but the image still doesn't appear.

I put the image under `public_html/myproject/images`. The image has name `dog.jpg`, and it's type is `image/x-generic`.

Comment: why width is null ? try change it

Comment: It doesn't matter. I tried other link and it works. Only the link from my server fails.

Comment: Which version of RN are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

try something link this:

```
<img src="https://myserver/images/1.jpg" style="height: 200, width: null, flex: 1"/>
```